# Ionic email composer crash on android 11

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I had implemented the `cordova-plugin-email-composer` in my project and it works well before that but after upgrading to `cordova-android@10.0.0` the app crashed when trigger the `this.emailcomposer.open(email)`.

Only android 11 was crashing and android 8 works fine. When I change back to `cordova-android@9.0.0`, both android 8 and 11 works fine.

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/issues/350

I found someone having the same problem. So I wonder is a bug or we need to write up something on the `config.xml`

Comment: try updating your android v to  `cordova-android@10.1.1`. 10.0.0 have some issues.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply I had just tested using `cordova-android@10.1.1` it builds successfully but crashes right after the app open.

Comment: Ok I successfully build the android `cordova-android@10.1.1 ` but the problem still exists. I also tried adding the permission on the `config.xml` but crashes right after the app open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for the ionic email composer crashing issue.
In the URL link below was the documentation for the changes in android 11.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-all#share-content-uris

Need to add the below code in the config.xml under android

```
<config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION" />
                </config-file>
    <config-file parent="/manifest/queries" target="AndroidManifest.xml" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                <package android:name="com.google.android.gm" />
                <package android:name="com.microsoft.office.outlook" />
                <package android:name="com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail" />
                <intent>
                    <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
                </intent>
            </config-file>
```