# Solution needed, email composer crashes the app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, plugins

I have a problem with cordova-plugin-email-composer: sending email was working in the app for some time, but today I found out it's not working anymore - upon calling `.open` on EmailComposer the app closes. Calling `.isAvailable()` and `.getClients()` returns undefined.

None of the suggestions at [Ionic email composer crash on android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70470649/ionic-email-composer-crash-on-android-11) work for me. Since I was using @ionic-native/email-composer I also went with @awesome-cordova-plugins/email-composer but it didn't fix the issue either.

Any suggestions for fixes or alternatives?

*I'm sorry if someone thinks there's no need for this question since it's asked in that link above, but since it's with accepted answer, I figured I should ask a new one. Powers-that-be: feel free to delete this question if it's inappropriate or unnecessary in your opinion.*

Answer (score 1):

After a month of going back-and-forth to fixing this problem with my app, I finally found a solution with the help and guidelines of a kind soul answering my question on the plugin's GitHub repo.

So:

1. Installed a 6.1.1 gradle version and in Android Studio > Gradle Settings pointed the Gradle to installation folder.
2. Added `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip` to gradle-wrapper.properties.
3. Added

```
    <queries>
          <intent>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <data android:scheme="*" />
          </intent>
    </queries>
```

inside of AndroidManifest.xml

4. Finally set `targetSdkVersion = 30` in variables.gradle.